# Quadrupole formula in TT gauge

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, gauge

In weak gravity limit, we can derive the celebrated quadrupole formula in Lorenz gauge $\partial^{\mu} \bar{h}_{\mu \nu} = 0$:
$$
\bar{h}_{ij} = \frac{2G}{r}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}I_{ij}(t_r)
$$

To get $h^{TT}_{ij}$ in transverse traceless gauge, one needs to find a gauge transformation $h_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow h_{\mu \nu} + 2\partial_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}$, such that
$$
h = 0\quad h_{0 \nu} = 0 \quad \partial^{\mu}\bar{h}_{\mu \nu} = 0.
$$
But Sean Carroll says that we can just project the $h_{\mu \nu}$ in Lorenz gauge by the transverse-traceless projector to get $h^{TT}_{\mu \nu}$.
The definition of transverse-traceless projector is:
$$
\mathcal{P}_{j k m n} \equiv P_{j m} P_{k n}-\frac{1}{2} P_{j k} P_{m n}
$$
where
$$
P_{j k} \equiv \delta_{j k}-n_{j} n_{k}
$$
and $n^i$ is the unit vector normal to the wavefront.

The quadrupole formula after projection becomes
$$
\bar{h}^{TT}_{ij} = \frac{2G}{r}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}I^{TT}_{ij}(t_r),
$$
but how to prove that such projection can be done by a gauge transformation? In other words, why we can get the same result by simply applying transverse-traceless projector instead of solving a bunch of differential equations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transverse traceless gauge in linearized GR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/574293/transverse-traceless-gauge-in-linearized-gr)

Comment: Not really. Indeed, we can go to TT gauge following the procedure mentioned in [transverse-traceless projector](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/574293/transverse-traceless-gauge-in-linearized-gr), but why we can get the same result by simply using transverse-traceless projector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you edited your question after my initial comment, I think that I now know what you were trying to ask.

Any metric perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$ (in any gauge) can be decomposed uniquely into several pieces, which correspond to the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ as outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar-vector-tensor_decomposition):
$$h_{00} = -2\phi \\ h_{0i} = \beta_i + \partial_i \lambda \\ h_{ij} = h^{\text{TT}}_{ij} +  \underbrace{\frac{1}{3} \psi \delta_{ij}}_{\text{trace}} + \underbrace{\partial_{(i} \omega_{j)}}_{\text{solenoidal}} + \underbrace{(\partial_i \partial_j - \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ij} \nabla^2) \theta}_{\text{longitudinal}}$$
with $$\psi = \delta^{ij}h_{ij} \\ \partial^i\beta_i = \partial^i\omega_i = 0 \\ \partial^i h^{\text{TT}}_{ij} = \delta^{ij}h^{\text{TT}}_{ij} = 0$$
and the boundary conditions that they must go to zero as $r \to \infty$. Under a gauge transformation $h_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu$, it can be shown that only $h^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$ remains invariant while all the other pieces change. This suggests that $h^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$ corresponds to something physical, as after all physical quantities do not depend on the choice of coordinates.

Using the pieces, three more gauge-invariant objects can be constructed: $$A = \psi - \nabla^2 \theta \\ B = \phi + \dot{\lambda} - \frac{1}{2} \ddot{\theta} \\ C_i = \beta_i - \frac{1}{2} \dot{\omega}_i$$

Decomposing the stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ in a similar way (which I will not bother repeating), and applying Einstein's equation, we get $$\nabla^2 A = \ldots \\ \nabla^2 B = \ldots \\ \nabla^2 C_i = \ldots \\ \Box^2 h^{\text{TT}}_{ij} = -16 \pi G T^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$$ where the dots correspond to the pieces of $T_{\mu\nu}$.

We have proven an important fact which is that **only** $h^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$ **contains the propagating gravitational waves**, as only $h^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$ obeys a wave equation. The rest of the pieces of $h_{\mu\nu}$ do not.

However, if we go by the traditional method which is to first impose the Lorentz gauge, we get $\Box^2 \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = -16 \pi G T_{\mu\nu}$, which seems to make the entire $h_{\mu\nu}$ obey a wave equation. This obscures the important fact that the other pieces inside are only waving because of gauge choice. These are removed when we impose the TT gauge on top of the Lorentz gauge.

Therefore, we have two ways to get to the TT gauge from an arbitrary starting point. The first way (which always works) is to find $\xi_\mu$ explicitly by solving differential equations and using it to transform the gauge such that all the other pieces of $h_{\mu\nu}$ go to zero except $h^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$ (you can check that this requires $8$ constraints, which is consistent with $10-8=2$ degrees of freedom corresponding to the two polarizations of gravitational waves). This is shown [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/574539).

The second way (which applies to unidirectional waves) is to use the projection operator in the direction of propagation, which simply removes the rest of the pieces, leaving $h^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$ behind (remember that $h^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$ is gauge-invariant, anyway!)

Therefore, with either method, we arrive at the desired outcome which is to obtain $h^{\text{TT}}_{ij}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one more question. As you said, $h^{TT}_{ij}$ is a gauge-invariant quantity, so we can always use the projection to get the transverse-traceless piece, which is just the perturbation metric in TT gauge. However, I learned that TT gauge can only be taken when there is no matter in the region.

Comment: @Hao Yes, that is correct. The metric in GR has six degrees of freedom, of which only two are radiative and the remaining coming from sources.  This is why the TT gauge is not a true "gauge" in the sense that it has eight constraints and therefore over-determines the metric. In my opinion, the TT gauge is better understood as *the radiative part of the metric* rather than a gauge. This is why we can only use it in regions of vacuum. There are other gauges, such as the one mentioned [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.3927.pdf), that attempt to combine gravitational waves with sources.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, while studying general relativity, I also found myself puzzled by this question. Although it may be a bit late, I came across a comprehensive article that explains that in fact this is actually just an approximation.:https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.09914

To be short, the Transverse-Traceless(TT) decomposition of the metric perturbation involves derivatives with respect to coordinates, which means that it's not local. However, the projection way is of course local, so they are in fact quite different.

Then, the article demonstrates that under the assumption of an isolated source, despite the many differences, both methods yield the same observables such as the power of gravitational waves. However, there are differences in terms of angular momentum results.